# Rsponsive overlapping image with css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image in a fullwidth div which is overlapping the div, so when the browser gets resized more of the image is shown/hidden but the image itself does not get resized. i got it working for the width but how can i achieve the same effect for the height?

Here is my test:
https://jsfiddle.net/g8h8umt3/

i got the width working with css:

```
#img-header{
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a image on how it suppose to work:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtvgP.jpg)

The image in the background should keep its size and the parent div should get smaller/larger depending on the screen size. I got the behaviour for the width but i dont know how to do it for the height of the image.

I also tried adding

```
#img-header{
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

but this does not seem to work

Comment: if I understand, you just want to add `width: 100%` or maybe `max-width: 100%` to the `img`

Comment: thats not what i want this will scale the picture smaller/larger depending on the screen size, what i want is that the image will keep its size and more of it is shown/hidden when changing the screen size. I edited my question maybe its more clear now. I dont know how to describe this problem properly :/

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/g8h8umt3/2/

Comment: thats exactly what i want thanks Michael! Can you write this as an answer so i can accept it? :)

Comment: Awesome. Submitted an answer with a couple of other alternatives, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to keep it's size and the to be hidden on all corners as the parent size changes, use `absolute` positioning for the image, and a combination of `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to put the image in the center of the parent, and the parent will scale on all sides of the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 $('#img-header-container').height($( window ).width()/3);
 
    $( window ).resize(function() {
  onResized();
 });
});

function onResized(){
 $('#img-header-container').height($( window ).width()/3);
}
```

```css
#img-header-container{
  width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#img-header{
  position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent Before</div>
<div id="img-header-container">
  <img src="https://clsimplex.com/images/releases/headers/quality-code.jpg" id="img-header"/>
</div>
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent After</div>
```

And for what it's worth, you don't have to use jquery to make the container 1/3rd of the window height. You can use viewport units (`vh`) with `calc()` for that.

```css
#img-header-container {
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#img-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent Before</div>
<div id="img-header-container">
  <img src="https://clsimplex.com/images/releases/headers/quality-code.jpg" id="img-header" />
</div>
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent After</div>
```

And FWIW v2.0, you could do this with a background image, then the `img` won't block the page load and it's less markup/css.

```css
#img-header-container {
  height: calc(100vh / 3);
  background: url('https://clsimplex.com/images/releases/headers/quality-code.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent Before</div>
<div id="img-header-container">
</div>
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent After</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood what you want to do
I give you an example of what I understood

```css
#img-header-container{
  width: 100%;
}

#img-header{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent Before</div>
<div id="img-header-container">
  <img src="https://clsimplex.com/images/releases/headers/quality-code.jpg" id="img-header"/>
</div>
<div style="min-height:50px">Conent After</div>
```

Comment: thats not what i want this will scale the picture smaller/larger depending on the screen size, what i want is that the image will keep its size and more of it is shown/hidden when changing the screen size. I edited my question maybe its more clear now. I dont know how to describe this problem properly :/